# How do I perform a join between two other joins

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'd like to know how to do 2 execution plans: "traditional" execution plan joins (A with B) and then C.
The "new" plan joins (A with B) then (A with C) and then joins the result of those joins so there would be 3 joins. *How would I code the traditional and new plan in Oracle SQLPlus* given the code below? I also need to measure the time complexity of both methods to show that the new plan takes less time, which I believe I just do with set timer on; The joins can be on whatever attributes work. Same with select statements. I made a artist, b album, c track, and d played.

Here's the database:

```
    CREATE TABLE artist(
    artist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    artist_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id)
  );

CREATE TABLE album (
    artist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    album_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    album_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id,album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES artist(artist_id)
);

CREATE TABLE track (
    track_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    track_name CHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
    artist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    album_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id,album_id,track_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id)          REFERENCES artist(artist_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id,album_id) REFERENCES album(artist_id,album_id)
);

CREATE TABLE played (
    artist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    album_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    track_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    played date DEFAULT sysdate, -- TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id,album_id,track_id,played),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id)          REFERENCES artist(artist_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id,album_id) REFERENCES album(artist_id,album_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id,album_id,track_id)   REFERENCES track(artist_id,album_id,track_id)
);


INSERT INTO artist VALUES (1, 'New Order');
INSERT INTO artist VALUES (2, 'Nick Cave  The Bad Seeds');
INSERT INTO artist VALUES (3, 'Miles Davis');
INSERT INTO artist VALUES (4, 'The Rolling Stones');
INSERT INTO artist VALUES (5, 'The Stone Roses');
INSERT INTO artist VALUES (6, 'Kylie Minogue');

INSERT INTO album VALUES (2, 1, 'Let Love In');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 1, 'Retro - John McCready FAN');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 2, 'Substance (Disc 2)');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 3, 'Retro - Miranda Sawyer POP');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 4, 'Retro - New Order / Bobby Gillespie LIVE');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (3, 1, 'Live Around The World');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (3, 2, 'In A Silent Way');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 5, 'Power, Corruption  Lies');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (4, 1, 'Exile On Main Street');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 6, 'Substance 1987 (Disc 1)');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (5, 1, 'Second Coming');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (6, 1, 'Light Years');
INSERT INTO album VALUES (1, 7, 'Brotherhood');


INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Do You Love Me?',2,1,'5.95');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Nobodys Baby Now',2,1,'3.87');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Loverman',2,1,'6.37');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Jangling Jack',2,1,'2.78');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Red Right Hand',2,1,'6.18');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'I Let Love In',2,1,'4.25');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Thirsty Dog',2,1,'3.81');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Aint Gonna Rain Anymore',2,1,'3.77');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Lay Me Low',2,1,'5.15');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Do You Love Me? (Part Two)',2,1,'6.23');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Elegia',1,1,'4.93');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'In A Lonely Place',1,1,'6.26');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Procession',1,1,'4.47');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Your Silent Face',1,1,'5.99');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Sunrise',1,1,'6.01');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Lets Go',1,1,'3.90');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Broken Promise',1,1,'3.76');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Dreams Never End',1,1,'3.20');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Cries And Whispers',1,1,'3.42');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'All Day Long',1,1,'5.18');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Sooner Than You Think',1,1,'5.21');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'Leave Me Alone',1,1,'4.67');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'Lonesome Tonight',1,1,'5.19');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (13,'Every Little Counts',1,1,'4.47');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (14,'Run Wild',1,1,'3.95');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'In A Lonely Place',1,2,'6.30');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Procession',1,2,'4.46');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Mesh',1,2,'3.44');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Hurt',1,2,'6.98');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'The Beach',1,2,'7.32');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Confusion',1,2,'7.64');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Lonesome Tonight',1,2,'5.20');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Murder',1,2,'3.93');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Thieves Like Us',1,2,'6.95');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Kiss Of Death',1,2,'7.05');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Shame Of The Nation',1,2,'7.91');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'1963',1,2,'5.63');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Fine Time',1,3,'4.71');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Temptation',1,3,'8.71');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'True Faith',1,3,'5.88');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'The Perfect Kiss',1,3,'4.83');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Ceremony',1,3,'4.41');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Regret',1,3,'4.14');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Crystal',1,3,'6.83');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Bizarre Love Triangle',1,3,'4.35');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Confusion',1,3,'8.22');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Round And Round',1,3,'4.52');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Blue Monday',1,3,'7.48');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'Brutal',1,3,'4.83');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'Slow Jam',1,3,'4.88');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (13,'Everyone Everywhere',1,3,'4.43');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Ceremony [Studio 54, Barcelona 7/7/84]',1,4,'4.82');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Procession [Polytechnic of Central London, London 6/12/85]',1,4,'3.57');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Everythings Gone Green [Tolworth Recreation Centre, London 12/3/85]',1,4,'5.25');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'In A Lonely Place [Glastonbury Festival 20/6/81]',1,4,'5.55');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Age Of Consent [Spectrum Arena, Warrington 1/3/86]',1,4,'5.04');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Elegia [Glastonbury Festival 19/6/87]',1,4,'4.77');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'The Perfect Kiss [Glastonbury Festival 19/6/87]',1,4,'9.73');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Fine Time [Popular Creek Music Theatre, Chicago 30/6/89]',1,4,'5.04');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'World [Starplex Amphitheatre, Dallas 21/7/93]',1,4,'4.81');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Regret [Reading Festival 29/8/93]',1,4,'4.03');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'As It Is When It Was [Reading Festival 29/8/93]',1,4,'3.80');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'Intermission By Alan Wise [Olympia, Paris 12/11/01]',1,4,'1.34');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'Crystal [Big Day Out, Gold Coast 20/1/02]',1,4,'6.86');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (13,'Turn My Way [Olympia, Liverpool 18/7/01]',1,4,'4.96');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (14,'Temptation [Big Day Out, Gold Coast 20/1/02]',1,4,'7.79');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'In A Silent Way',3,1,'1.81');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Intruder',3,1,'4.87');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'New Blues',3,1,'5.58');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Human Nature',3,1,'12.80');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Mr. Pastorius',3,1,'3.54');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Amandla',3,1,'5.87');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Wrinkle',3,1,'7.28');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Tutu',3,1,'8.89');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Full Nelson',3,1,'2.81');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Time After Time',3,1,'9.98');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Hannibal',3,1,'7.37');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Shhh/Peaceful',3,2,'16.67');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'In A Silent Way/It\s About That Time',3,2,'16.67');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Age Of Consent',1,5,'5.26');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'We All Stand',1,5,'5.24');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'The Village',1,5,'4.62');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'5 8 6',1,5,'7.52');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Your Silent Face',1,5,'6.00');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Ultraviolence',1,5,'4.87');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Ecstasy',1,5,'4.42');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Leave Me Alone',1,5,'4.69');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Rocks Off',4,1,'4.54');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Rip This Joint',4,1,'2.38');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Shake Your Hips',4,1,'3.00');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Casino Boogie',4,1,'3.57');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Tumbling Dice',4,1,'3.79');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Sweet Virginia',4,1,'4.44');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Torn Frayed',4,1,'4.30');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Sweet Black Angel',4,1,'2.97');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Loving Cup',4,1,'4.43');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Happy',4,1,'3.08');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Turd On The Run',4,1,'2.64');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'Ventilator Blues',4,1,'3.40');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'I Just Want To See His Face',4,1,'2.90');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (13,'Let It Loose',4,1,'5.31');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (14,'All Down The Line',4,1,'3.84');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (15,'Stop Breaking Down',4,1,'4.57');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (16,'Shine A Light',4,1,'4.28');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (17,'Soul Survivor',4,1,'3.82');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Ceremony',1,6,'4.42');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Everythings Gone Green',1,6,'5.51');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Temptation',1,6,'6.99');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Blue Monday',1,6,'7.49');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Confusion',1,6,'4.72');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Thieves Like Us',1,6,'6.61');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Perfect Kiss',1,6,'8.04');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Subculture',1,6,'4.80');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Shellshock',1,6,'6.48');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'State of the Nation',1,6,'6.54');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Bizarre Love Triangle',1,6,'6.74');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'True Faith',1,6,'5.93');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Breaking Into Heaven',5,1,'11.37');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Driving South',5,1,'5.17');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Ten Storey Love Song',5,1,'4.50');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Daybreak',5,1,'6.56');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Your Star Will Shine',5,1,'2.99');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Straight To The Man',5,1,'3.26');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Begging You',5,1,'4.94');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Tightrope',5,1,'4.45');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Good Times',5,1,'5.67');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Tears',5,1,'6.84');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'How Do You Sleep',5,1,'4.99');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'Love Spreads',5,1,'5.79');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'Untitled',5,1,'6.43');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'Spinning Around',6,1,'3.46');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'On A Night Like This',6,1,'3.55');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'So Now Goodbye',6,1,'3.62');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'Disco Down',6,1,'3.96');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Loveboat',6,1,'4.18');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Koocachoo',6,1,'4.00');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Your Disco Needs You',6,1,'3.56');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'Please Stay',6,1,'4.14');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Bittersweet Goodbye',6,1,'3.72');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Butterfly',6,1,'4.16');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (10,'Under The Influence Of Love',6,1,'3.40');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (11,'I am  So High',6,1,'3.55');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (12,'Kids',6,1,'4.34');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (0,'State of the Nation',1,7,'6.56');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (1,'Every Little Counts',1,7,'4.48');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (2,'Angel Dust',1,7,'3.73');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (3,'All Day Long',1,7,'5.21');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (4,'Bizarre Love Triangle',1,7,'4.37');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (5,'Way of Life',1,7,'4.11');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (6,'Broken Promise',1,7,'3.80');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (7,'As It Is When It Was',1,7,'3.77');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (8,'Weirdo',1,7,'3.89');
INSERT INTO track VALUES (9,'Paradise',1,7,'3.86');

INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 0, '5-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 1, '25-feb-2020');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 2, '15-jan-2020');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 3, '7-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 4, '9-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 5, '21-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 6, '11-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (1, 3, 7, '30-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (3, 1, 0, '8-jan-2020');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (3, 1, 1, '28-jan-2019');
INSERT INTO played VALUES (3, 1, 2, '3-jan-2019');
```

Comment: What "image in the link"?

Comment: When you say "plan", do you mean an "execution plan"?

Comment: You should use the `join`s that implement the logic that you need -- which is not explained.  You should not choose a query based on which has a better execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, because it's imposing bizarre restrictions that we can't really assess, but I don't mind telling you how to join two joins

You already know how to join three tables in the normal/traditional/sensible sense. Here's how to join them as you ask:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM
  (SELECT a.id, ... FROM a JOIN b ON ...) ab 
  JOIN (SELECT a.id, ... FROM a JOIN c ON ...) ac ON ac.id = ab.id
```

Newsflash: sql join operates on "blocks of data", not just tables. A table is a block of data, but so is the output of a SELECT. You can take any data output by a select and feed it into anywhere that is expecting a block of data for query purposes. You can even turn them into pseudotables in most DBs with WITH

```
WITH ab as (SELECT a.id, ... FROM a JOIN b ON ...),
ac as (SELECT a.id, ... FROM a JOIN c ON ...)

SELECT ... 
FROM ab JOIN ac ON ac.id = ab.id
```

Which also makes them easy to reuse multiple times in the same query

```
SELECT ... 
FROM 
  ab 
  JOIN ac ac1 ON ac1.id = ab.id
  JOIN ac ac2 ON ac2.id = ab.id
```

Newsflash 2: It's quite likely the optimizer will look at either subquery form or the WITH form and rewrite it so it executed identically to what you already have with the two joins route. A large part of getting a DB to be the market leader in terms of performance is rewriting the garbage that developers throw into it, into something that performs as well as possible. After working out the set of join operations these queries all boil down to the same thing and you probably won't see any change in how your query is executed

Comment: I just tried that and made my code as follows:
WITH ab as (SELECT * FROM artist a JOIN album ab ON a.artist_id=ab.artist_id),
ac as (SELECT * FROM track t JOIN played p ON p.track_id=t.track_id)
SELECT * 
FROM ab JOIN ac ON ac.artist_id = ab.artist_id;

However I get that ab.artist_ID is an invalid identifier, same with ac.artist_id

Comment: Does your table have a column artist_id? Or is it just called id? You'll have to give it an alias when you select it (inside the WITH) if you want it called something else. One of the problems of posting a question using only abstract names (rather than the actual columns you have) is that *we then don't know* your actual column names so we can only give abstract responses. If you're confident that you can translate back any advice received into what you actually have then go ahead. If you aren't then post actual names so we can give them in answers

Comment: updated the question to make it a lot more specific

Comment: You should avoid editing questions so drastically that it invalidates existing answers. As it is, the question no longer makes sense, because it now requires 3 joins no matter what. A join B join C join D is the same as (A join B) join (C joinD) and both mention "join" 3 times

Comment: Sorry I was having a back and forth with my professor and he mislead me. I believe my original understanding is correct with there just being 3 tables: A, b, C.

Comment: So, think again about "blocks of data". Person is a table; a block of data. `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person` generates a block of data (just names) that can be queried: `SELECT firstname FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person)x`. Critically the outer query cannot access any data from person that was not selected. This doesn't work: `SELECT age FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Person)x` - age is not available because it's not in the output datablock. Nor this: `SELECT firstname FROM (SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname FROM Person)x` - firstname doesn't exist